# The total within sum of squares gradually decreases in K-means algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

Show that for K-means algorithm,

$ \sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{i \in C_k} d(X_i,\bar{X_k}) \ge \sum_{j=1}^K \sum_{i \in C_j^\prime} d(X_i,\bar{X_j^\prime})$,

where d is the squared Euclidean distance,$\bar{X_k} \in R^p$ is the centroid of the cluster determined by $C_k$, $C_j^\prime= \{ i: d(X_i,\bar{X_j^\prime})= min_{k=1,...,K}d(X_i,\bar{X_k})\}$, and $\bar{X_j^\prime}$ is the centroid of the cluster determined by $C_j^\prime$

My understanding:

I think this inequality guarantees the convergence of the K-means algorithm. We need to incorporate $ C_k= \cup_{j=1}^K (C_k \cap C_j^\prime)$ to prove this inequality. However, what happening here is that the cost function i.e. the total within sum of squares is gradually decreasing for a new updated centroid, but I don't know how to show this here. I appreciate your suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your definition of $C'_j$ is alright ? You are using $\bar{X'}_j$ to define $C'_j$ , and then using $C'_j$ to define $\bar{X'}_j$. Please check once, and let us know if my doubt is legitimate.

Comment: @Kolmogorov $C_j^\prime$ is alright! I have double checked. I guess $C_j^\prime$ are the new clusters defined by the new centroids.